# Cassnadra Java Driver 2.1 Object Mapper. Error while checking frozen type

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, object-relational-model

I have a cassandra table which is holding a multimap kind of data structure. I don't want to change the table structure as requirement is to fetch all cluster, server based on env and domain name.

```
CREATE TABLE CLUSTER_DETAILS (Environment text,DomainName text,ApplicationName text,ClusterServerMap map<text, frozen <list<frozen <SERVER_INSTANCE>>>>,LastUpdatedAt timestamp, PRIMARY KEY ((Environment,DomainName), ApplicationName)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ApplicationName asc);
```

Server_Instance is again a User Definied Data type.

i am using cassandra-driver-mapping to populate the data in the table from my Java application. **Now i am not able to figure out what annotation i should be using to map the ClusterServerMap field to my Object property.**

i've tried 
@Frozen (Map < Text, Frozen < LIST < FROZEN < SERVER_INSTANCE>>>)
but that is throwing error saying

> Error while checking frozen types on field clusterServerMap of entity WLClusterDetails: expected '>' (map<  text, frozen < list< frozen < SERVER_INSTANCE>>>> [44])

and not sure whether @Frozenvalue will satisfy the requirement. Is ther any other annotation to deal with this scenario. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** The Server_Instance UDF is just a plain object with bunch of strings and ints.

> create type server_instance (ClusterName text, ServerName text, ClusterWeight int, ActivationTime bigint, CurrentMachine text, HealthState int, State text);

Comment: It's a good idea to add the UDF declaration, it will be helpful in answering the question.